Understanding convolution and distributions
I'm learning about distributions and some important part is its behaviour under the convolution operation. Given a distribution $T\in D'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and a function $\varphi\in D(\mathbb{R}^n)$, my book defines the convolution of $T$ with $\varphi$ as the function $T*\varphi$ which associates to every $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ $$(T*\varphi)(x):=T(\tau_x\tilde{\varphi}),$$ where $\tau_x(f)(y)=f(y-x),$ and $\tilde{f}(y)=f(-y).$ When the distribution comes from some locally integrable function $f$, the definition coincides with the usual convolution of locally integrable functions $$(T*\varphi)(x)=T(\tau_x\tilde{\varphi})=\int f(y)\varphi(x-y)dy=(f*\varphi)(x).$$
Howeverm in some other references, the convolution of a distribution with a test function is defined as a distribution, $$(T*\varphi)(\phi):=T(\tilde{\varphi}*\phi),$$ for every $\phi\in D(\mathbb{R}^n).$ My intuition is that the different definitions hide the notation abuse that is always done with the distributions, treating them like functions and linear operators without changing the notation, i.e., if a distribution $T$ comes from a locally integrable function $f$, the distribution that arises from $f$ is also denoted as $f$ instead of $T$ or $T_f$, which is far more appropiated. To see that both definitions are in some way equivalent i tried to prove, from the definitons of convolution as a new function, that the distribution that it generates is the same distribution of the second definition. Let $G=G_{(T*\varphi)}$ the distribution generated by the convolution $T*\varphi$, i.e., $$G(\phi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(T*\varphi)(x)\phi(x)dx.$$ Suppose that $T$ comes from a locally integrable function $f$, then $$G(\phi)=\int(T*\varphi)(x)\phi(x)dx=\int\left(\int f(y)\varphi(x-y)dy\right)\phi(x)dx=\int\int f(y)\varphi(x-y)\phi(x)dydx=\int\int f(y)\varphi(x-y)\phi(x)dxdy=\int f(y)\left(\int \varphi(x-y)\phi(x)dx\right)dy=\int f(y)(\phi*\tilde{\varphi})(y)dy=T(\phi*\tilde{\varphi})=T(\tilde{\varphi}*\phi)=(T*\varphi)(\phi).$$ So, when $T$ comes from a locally integrable function, both definitions of convolution of distribution with a function coincide in the sense that the distribution originated by the convolution as a function coincide with the definition of convolution as distribution. Am i right? I don't know if im getting this right, and how to prove that both definitions coincide with a general distribution $T$. Thanks in advance!

The convolution $\overline\varphi*\phi$ in the right hand side of the second definition can be considered as a limit of Riemann sums. You need to establish that the Riemann sums converge not only for every $y$ separately, but as limits of functions of $y$ in the topology of the test functions. Since $T$ is a continuous linear functional with respect to that topology, this enables you to exchange the operation $T$ with the integration.

As @Lieven said showing the two definitions agree involves a mixed "Fubini Theorem" which exchanges the $T$ operation and integration which is the distribution associated to the constant function equal to $1$. Using Riemann sums is a pedestrian way of doing that. For a more canonical approach to this commutation, see this MO answer  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72450/can-distribution-theory-be-developed-riemann-free/351028#351028
